# How to remove the merged datatable from the datatable using C#.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, datatable

I have two datatables D1 and D2.
     I merged the datatable D2 with D1 as follows:

```
       D1.Merge(D2);
```

But now, I want to remove the DataTable D2 from the D1. How to achieve this?

Comment: well not sure but maybe you could use `GetChanges()` for it, if not why not merge them in a separate temp DataTable (`D3`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most beautiful solution, but you can consider adding a distinctive column to your tables. I set those values by hand, but for example if your datatables are filled from a SQL query, you can easily add that distinctive column in those queries and use them accordingly.

```
D1.Columns.Add("ORIGINAL_DATATABLE_NAME", typeof(int));
D2.Columns.Add("ORIGINAL_DATATABLE_NAME", typeof(int));

foreach(DataRow row in D1.Rows)
    row["ORIGINAL_DATATABLE_NAME"] = 1;

foreach(DataRow row in D2.Rows)
    row["ORIGINAL_DATATABLE_NAME"] = 2;

D1.Merge(D2);

DataRow[] rows = D1.Select("ORIGINAL_DATATABLE_NAME=1", "");

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Merge(rows, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("ORIGINAL_DATATABLE_NAME");
```